# ngClass binding not updating via directive communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I want to nest two directives and the `inner directive` has a `ng-class` bound to a function that takes a scope attribute from inner and outer scopes and return a Boolean

This is the HTML:

```
<ul my-toolbar disabled-when="myCtrl.isProcessing" >
  <li my-action-button action="myCtrl.action()" disable-when="myCtrl.isSad()" />
</ul>
```

This is my outer directive:

```
myApp.directive("myToolbar", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      disabled: '=disabledWhen'
    },
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.isDisabled = function() {
        return $scope.disabled;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

And this is my inner directive:

```
myApp.directive("myActionButton", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      action: '&',
      disabled: '=disabledWhen'
    },
    replace: true,
    template: "<li ng-class='{disabled: isDisabled()}'><a ng-click='isDisabled() || action()' /></li>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, toolbarCtrl) {
        scope.isDisabled = function() {
          return toolbarCtrl.isDisabled() || scope.disabled;
        };
    }
  };
});
```

Now the problem is that the `ng-class='{disabled: isDisabled()}'` binding is initialized once in the beginning but not updated when `myCtrl.isProcessing` changes!

Can someone please explain why? and how can I fix this without changing my design?

Comment: "`ng-class='{disabled: isDisabled()}` binding is initialized once in the beginning" -- what makes you think this is even happening?

Comment: I suggest putting your code into a jsfiddle or plunker.  It will help both you and us to find out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan as requested I put my `angular code` in a fiddle and (this is part that's irritating me now) it works!

http://jsfiddle.net/shantanusinghal/ST3kH/1/

Now, I'll go back to seeing why it doesn't work for me in my production code!! *puzzled